# uml pattern similar to GoF composite

Tags: design-patterns, hierarchy, uml, composite

How can I communicate the basic idea of a hierarchy / tree of alltogether variable but fixed height for one of its instance; leaves are disjunct from nodes, they are all located on the same, least level and every branch from the root to the leaves has the same length.

Like a really simple, uniform org chart or uniform directory structure e.g.,

```
rootdir
|- subdir
  |-- subsubdir
    |--- file
    |--- file
    |--- file
  |-- subsubdir
    |--- file
|- subdir
  |-- subsubdir
    |--- file
```

where all files are located at level 3 and each subtree has the same height like its siblings. No intermediate nodes of different height or files on a different then least level exist.

What extra notation would convey (maybe together with a composite pattern), this restriction. Or more elegantly, is there any other pattern for hierarchical structures or exactly this structure?

related: [UML notation for 'ending' composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259335/uml-notation-for-ending-composition)

Answer (score 0):

I used the OCL to indicate the constraint. Actually, the composite pattern doesn't fit here anyway since leaves are not supposed to exist in "sublevels". It is much simpler:

[image]

Hope that I'm right with that.